# maven - remove -SNAPSHOT from properties tag in pom.xml

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml, versions-maven-plugin

The parent pom.xml of my application contains the following snippet:

```
...
<version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<properties>
    <property.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</property.version>
</properties>
```

Essentially, I would like to update both the -SNAPSHOT versions to release versions. i.e., I want my resultant pom.xml to be like:

```
...
<version>2.0</version>
...
<properties>
    <property.version>1.0</property.version>
</properties>
```

[*Note: v1.0 of `<property.version>` is not yet deployed to the artifactory and also might not be the latest version available*
*There might exist more properties with SNAPSHOT versions that I do not want to update to release versions*]

I figured out a way to update the `<version>` using [maven versions:set plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#removeSnapshot). However, I could not find any solution for updating the version (by removing -SNAPSHOT) inside the `<properties>` tag.

I've looked at documentations for versions:update-properties, versions:update-property.

I am trying to achieve this by using the mvn versions plugin, otherwise I would have to write a script (eg. shell) which would parse and do the needful.

Comment: What is the problem with ` versions:update-property`? And why do you need such property?

Comment: `versions:update-property` is trying to update to the latest version available in my artifactory, which is not something I am wanting.

Comment: You knwo there is an property: `-DnewVersion=XXX`?